# Want to remove or obfuscate credit card info from xml stored as text

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

We have a log table that has a varchar(max) field, that contains a copy of xml passed back and forth in remote system calls.

The problem is that we have credit card data stored in the column, stored openly. Our goal to is to obfuscate, mask OR delete the credit card data.  The format of the xml is varied. We know what the format will be in most cases.

So lets say the table is titled RemoteSysLog, and the field storing the text is titled InBoundMessage.

Any ideas on a solution?

we have considered

1. use the xml.remove functionality
2. use some sort of pattern matching for 16 digit numbers and replace with xxxxx( not sure what to use
3. replace the nodes with standard replace, substring, charindex string processing routines.

There are multiple sources that are logging to this table.So the company does NOT want to edit all the source code for those 'legacy' apps. So the solution needs to be within this scope.

Comment: **Do not** use standard string methods to manipulate XML.  Use a proper XML parser (like LINQ to XML on the .NET side).   Pattern matching may be your best bet, but be careful that there aren't other instances where you can have a field with 16 numbers that *isn't* a credit card number.

Comment: Why in the world are you storing credit card information ANYWHERE in plain text??? You don't need to obfuscate the data you need to restructure your process entirely with regards to handling this type of information.

Comment: 16 digit masking wouldn't help your AMEX customers.  Ideally whatever service that's posting that xml to the table needs to have the CC info stripped from it.

Comment: Obfuscation isn't good enough - any time it's passed around, it should be encrypted.  You don't want to be on the evening news.  I'd say that since it's logging, just don't send it.

Answer (score 4):

The log service should cleanse the payment information before storing the messages...it's just too risky.  Even if you make a pass afterwards to redact the CC info, your database and transaction backups may still contain the information you meant to wipe.

Since you're describing XML messages in need of transformation, my go-to approach would involve xslt.

[Something like this.](http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2Cs)

Comment: Unfortunately, we have multiple c# programs doing the updates to this table. So yes, that would be the best solution, but time wise and maintenance wise, it's not what the company wants :(

Comment: Consider creating a service layer for this functionality, and update each system that talks to this data.  Done properly, it really shouldn't cost too much effort.  In any case, employ as many compensating measures as you can, and be sure to use an XML technology to manipulate XML documents whenever possible.  Definitely sanitize whatever you can before taking full backups, which tend to have a shelf life due to retention.  Perhaps this is not such a big concern for a diagnostic logging application.